# To find data from one of the many collection and to return true value in Python pymongo

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have mongo db and im using pymongo to find an data in one of the many collection and if i found one i want to stop the and return true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to find weather the record is there or not:

```
  test =  bool(db.collection_1.find_one({'key': key}) or db.collection_2.find_one({'key1':)  key1})
   if test:
        print "found"
   else:
        print "not found"
```

Answer (score 2):

Pymongo has a find_one() method. 
Check it out [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one).